# How to deal with int from response when double expected?

Tags: dart

I expect double value from responce, but sometimes int value comes from responce.
How to deal with it?

```
double rate = jsonResponse['rate']; //rate may be int from response
return rate.round();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `toDouble` method for both the `int` and `double` classes as they both inherit that method from the `num` class where this method is defined. So you can do:

```dart
double rate = jsonResponse['rate'].toDouble();
return rate.round();
```

to guarantee you never experience an issue.

Answer (score 2):

In this case you can use the [num class](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/num-class.html). As the documentation states:

> An integer or floating-point number.

It contains the `round` method that your example uses, and also `toDouble` and `toInt` if needed.

So in your example you can use:

```
num rate = jsonResponse['rate']; //rate may be int from response
return rate.round();
```